# How to backup/restore NVidia user created custom resolutions?

Tags: backup, resolution, nvidia

I'd like to backup NVidia custom resolution settings I added to my 144Hz monitor (I added also custom 60, 90, 120Hz modes). Now I'm afraid on next driver clean update (or after DDU pass) to loose these settings.
How can I backup up them?
Where are them stored in the registry (maybe)?

Comment: is it in "C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\Drs\nvdrsdb0.bin" and "C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\Drs\nvdrsdb1.bin" with the whole app profiles settings, and not in the registry?

Comment: As far as I know, this save setting may not work in the registry. Just like AMD, Usually includes graphics control software. The software may have the setting to export the custom resolution and save as a file. But  NVidia software seems doesn't have this setting. Backup nvdrsdb0.bin and nvdrsdb1.bin before you select the option to clean your settings and then restore nvdrsdb0.bin and nvdrsdb1.bin after the installation is complete. Or I consider that you may use some tools such as Nvidia Inspector.

Comment: My question was about screen res. Yes Nvidia Profile Inspector can backup and restore games/apps individual 3D settings, but I was wondering how to restore/backup custom screen resolutions.